# How to increment the dense rank based on condition

Tags: sql, dense-rank

Below enclosed is my requirement.

[image]

I want to increment the dense rank function with the cap of each 5 line items by the partition of seller_state and warehouse_id code. for more clarification I have attached sample data of my requirement kindly help me on same.

below mentioned queries are my tries.

```
CASE
         WHEN icta_amount < 0 THEN (DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY seller_state ORDER BY seller_state,warehouse_id)) % 5
         WHEN icta_amount >= 0 THEN (DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY seller_state ORDER BY seller_state,warehouse_id))% 5
       END AS DENSE_RANK,
```

if i add warehouse_id in partition clause in all the places i am getting only 1 don't know the meaning of that.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please use text instead of images, as it's easier to use (e.g. copy/paste), not to mention screen-readers. It would also be very helpful to have the input to your expected output. And please don't tag your question with multiple specific RDBMS tags, only use the specific database you're using.

Comment: Sure will change in coming questions. Thanks for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: You have more than five with a rank of 4 in the output. Surely that was an oversight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start with a `row_number` partitioned by the `seller_state` and `warehouse_id`, floor that into groups of five, and then `dense_rank` over it:

```sql
SELECT seller_state, warehouse_id,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY seller_state, warehouse_id
                          ORDER BY seller_state, warehouse_id, FLOOR((rn - 1) / 5.0))
FROM   (SELECT seller_state, warehouse_id, 
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY seller_state, warehouse_id) AS RN
        FROM   mytable) t
```

**[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/914b9/3)**

Comment: @ravindrakdr This query doesn't even work. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=bf12a279e19dee050507a17f9ef66de6

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use `dense_rank()` then you'd want to use integer division to mark off the blocks:

```
with data as (
    select seller_state, warehouse_id, 
        row_number() over (partition by seller_state, warehouse_id
                           order by seller_state, warehouse_id) as rn
    from T
)
select seller_state, warehouse_id,
   dense_rank() over (order by seller_state, warehouse_id, (rn - 1) / 5) as rnk
from data;
```

You could also mark the spots where the counter should increase and them accumulate them. Count off each of the rows in the same state and warehouse. When you find one with where `row number mod 5 = 1` mark it as step for your ranking counter. This will immediately reset on a change of state or warehouse as desired:

```
sum(case when rn % 5 = 1 then 1 end)
    over (order by seller_state_warehouse_id, rn) as rnk
```

Some platforms do not require the `order by` where it is simply repeating the `partition by` columns while others do.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d32dba8fccbfb8b85a7eb26f4c8f4849